# Google Identity Platform pricing for custom tokens

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

The pricing for Google Identity Platform is covered [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing). Pricing per user falls in to one of two tiers depending on authentication method, and most methods are explicitly listed. However, [creating and using a custom token](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/create-custom-tokens) is not among the methods listed. Does anyone know at what tier custom token logins are billed?

Comment: Creating tokens is free.

Comment: [This](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-authentication) can also help you understand the types of authentication methods for Cloud logging.